# CSS change id with class in javascript

Tags: javascript

I wonder how to change style in javascript if i have css like this :

```
      #div_frame_text.show {
        -webkit-animation: TextinBottom 300ms ease both;
        animation: TextinBottom 300ms ease both;
      }

      #div_frame_text.hide {
        -webkit-animation: TextoutBottom 700ms ease both;
        animation: TextoutBottom 700ms ease both;
      }
```

i want to change animation and -webkit-animation with another animation. i have to tried change with code like this :

```
document.getElementById('div_frame_text').classList.contains('show').style['-webkit-animation'] = "Textin 300ms ease both"
document.getElementById('div_frame_text').classList.contains('show').style['animation'] = "Textin 300ms ease both"
```

is that possible?

Comment: To chnage CSS using Javscript, use the following format. `document.getElementById(id).style.property = new style`, so in your example `document.getElementById('div_frame_text.show).style.animation = "Textin 300ms ease both"`

Comment: `classList.contains('show')` returns true or false, neither of which has a style property. You need classList.add() and .remove()

Comment: but i want to change #div_frame_text.show not just change style by id @Anonymous

Comment: is that classList.add() to add a class? my goals is to change style in id with class (example : #div_frame_text.show) @ChrisG

Comment: Yes. Refer to the first comment to see how to change the current style of an element.

Comment: @ChrisG did you mean to use this `document.getElementById('div_frame_text.show).style.animation = "Textin 300ms ease both"` , this is have an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code below returns true

document.getElementById('div_frame_text').classList.contains('show')

if you add on true 
.style['animation'] = "Textin 300ms ease both"

it will give error animation is undefined 
You're basically give style to true not to the element
Cache the element into a variable and make a check if has show then inside the check add the stlyles;

Example:

```js
const frameText = document.getElementById('div_frame_text');
if (frameText.classList.contains('show')) {
    frameText.style.animation = "newanimation 300ms ease both";
}
```

My Advice to you console.log everything and if you have to use twice element selector put in a variable, if you have two times almost equal functionality create function with parameters for the elements and props that differs